# Issue querying Neo4j database for bus departure time

Tags: mysql, database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j. I am querying a graph database for a bus transit network. I have imported the data into my database but I am having some issue querying the database.

(1) Retrieve and show the shortest trip in the database at 8am

```
  MATCH p=shortestPath((o:Origin)-[:NEXT*..]-(dt:Destination))
  WHERE o.hour = 8
  return p ORDER BY LENGTH(p) ASC 
  LIMIT 1;
```

The above code produces "(no changes, no records)". I don't know what is wrong.

Node labels (16) are:

*, Agency, BusStop, Calendar, Day, Destination, Hour, Line, Minute, Month, Moves, Origin, Second, Stops, Streets, Trips, Year

Relationship types (13) are:

*, CONTAINS, DID_NOT_STOP_AT, ENDS_AT, HAS_DAY, HAS_MONTH, IS_COMPOSED_OF, MOVES_ON, NEXT, NEXT_DAY, RUNS, STARTS_AT, STOPS_AT, SUSPENSION_OF_MOVEMENT

Property Keys (46)

AgTimezone, AgTimezone, Arrivaltime, ArvDep, BusEvent, BusEventPlace, BusStopID, Departuretime, DestinationID, MoveID, OriginID, StopID, StopsID, agUrl, agencyID, cal_serviceID, date, day, dayid, endtime, hour, hourid, lLongName, lShortName, lType, latitude, lineID, longitude, minute, minuteid, month, monthid, sName, second, secondid, sequence, service_id, starttime, streetID, streetName, streetNoSpace, streetType, time, tripID, tripId, year, yearid

(2) Retrieve and show all the information from a single trip using all the entities (i.e. nodes and relationships)

```
  MATCH (n:Trip {tripID: '51-3-9'}) RETURN n LIMIT 1
```

I am not sure if the above code will return all the relationship because the result I got has four nodes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes queries do not work as intended when you try to do too much functions in one line (`MATCH`, `WITH` clause)... do not know why

try this

```
MATCH (o:Origin),(dt:Destination)
WHERE o.hour = 8
MATCH p=shortestPath((o)-[:NEXT*]-(dt))
return p ORDER BY LENGTH(p) ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

I do not know if this if your case but i think you want to match the `NEXT` relationship directed, because routes do not work both ways.
If so change your second `MATCH` to

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((o)-[:NEXT*]->(dt))
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomaž Bratanič! I have tried the code you suggested and changed the second MATCH but the result is "(no changes, no records)"

Comment: Can you try without where o.hour = 8

Comment: Or did you save hour as string ? So it would look like 'WHERE o.hour = "8"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated. I think the problem was the dataset I was working with. It was not reading any time less than two digit. A friend had to look at the dataset and reformated the time to hh:mm:ss. Therefore 8:10:10 became 08:10:10.